# $eq in mongodb in case of array

Tags: mongodb

After $lookup i got my the result as

```
 "comments": [
        {
            "_id": "58bd39a1518fb21803d8439d",                
            "comment": "Task1-comment",
            "photo": null,
            "userId": "589056bcc74270b81a890dce",                
        },
        {
            "_id": "58c034cc3c9af5141bca8a24",             
            "comment": "Dude",
            "photo": null,
            "userId": "589035b8603c0e9ebe5369c5",               
        }
```

now i need to set a boolean say "userComment", if any element matches the userId that i am giving as input. 
I wrote in aggregate pipeline as

```
$project: { "userComment": { $eq: ["$comments.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)] } },
```

then i input the userId as *589035b8603c0e9ebe5369c5*
but it returns userComment as false only.

How can i solve this? any help is appreciated

Comment: ids are simple strings, not ObjectId or guid?

Comment: ids are objectIds i tried as { $eq: ["$comments.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)] }

Comment: The mongoose schema type does not work for comparisons here, since it's actually a "wrapped object" that emits a proper `ObjectId` when called by "mongoose methods only". Instead [import the `ObjectId` function from the core driver](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/ObjectID.html). This will allow casting of your "string" to the correct type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it like this,

```
$project:{    
          "commentCount": {
                        "$filter": {
                            "input": "$comments",
                            "as": "comments",
                            "cond": { "$eq": ["$$comments.userId", mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)] }
                             }
                          }
          },
$project: { "userComments": { $cond: { if: { $gt: [{ $size: '$commentCount' }, 0] }, then: true, else: false } } }
```

used $project twice for the same, then got the expected result

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is before comparing values of an array which is "comments" you need to unwind the array first because only then you can move the cursor on the array inside the array so please write code `{$unwind: "$comments" }`, and after it apply your project query. And remember before unwinding you need to project "comments" array first.

Comment: thats i tried already as mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) but it wont get the expected output i need to compare with any userId in that comments array and if any match found needs to return true else false

Comment: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) is already a objectID but your "userId" is Strign so i think everything is fine, can you print typeof userId and see whether it is an String or not ?? because i think it's not a string.

Comment: also if this is not working working for you then you can project userID and manually in your code write comparison logic for that.

Comment: in project itself i am using this, i need to project only true or false

Comment: can you please have a relook at my answer.

Comment: @arunraj414 can you please try my answer it would also be correct ??

Comment: @arunraj414 did you try it ??

Comment: thnx @Sudhanshu , but i need it without unwinding some more queries are also associated with these which will break if unwind is used

Comment: without unwind you cannot write comparison operator($eq) inside an array because first the array must be unwind before moving the cursor.